# How can I programmatically determine if a system is a desktop or a server?

Tags: server, bash, package-management

Is there any way to distinguish between Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop?

I have a Bash script ([shameless plug](https://github.com/alixaxel/halBox)) that I use to set up lightweight web servers, and I've noticed that when I run this script on my own computer, my Ubuntu (Desktop) install gets all messed up - I'm pretty sure the culprit are the following lines of code:

```
echo -e "\e[1;32mDave, I'm removing the bloatware.\e[0m"

for halBox_package in apache2 bind9 nscd php portmap rsyslog samba sendmail; do
    if [[ -f /etc/init.d/$halBox_package ]]; then
        ( service $halBox_package stop ) > /dev/null
    fi

    ( apt-get -qq -y remove --purge "$halBox_package*" ) > /dev/null 2>&1
done
```

What I would like to do, is to detect whether the script is being ran in a Server flavour or not, so I can decide whether to purge those packages or not. If it's not possible to tell the flavors apart, can you tell me which package is necessary for Ubuntu Desktop to work properly?

Comment: @Rinzwind: `DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.10 DISTRIB_CODENAME=quantal DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.10"`. Nothing that I can use to tell if it's either Server or Desktop.

Comment: Fundamentally speaking, there's little difference between Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu.  The difference is primarily the fact that Desktop version comes with a GUI, but you can install a GUI onto the CLI ubuntu server.  Also, you can install server packages onto the GUI version of Ubuntu Desktop.  I'm not sure there is a sure-fire, clean-cut way to determine Desktop vs. Server installation media.

Comment: @Rinzwind: This is a server install. I also have 3 other VPS in 2 different providers with server editions and none of them shows the "server" string. I guess reading `lsb_release` just isn't reliable enough.

Comment: @TheLordofTime: Yes, I know they are pretty much the same. But I thought that maybe there was at least a crucial package that would differentiate between the two.

Comment: As a follow up note, the issue was the package regular expression, changing it to `( apt-get -qq -y remove --purge "^$halBox_package*" )` worked on both Server and Desktop flavors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Command

```
dpkg -l ubuntu-desktop
```

Result:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  ubuntu-desktop 1.287        i386         The Ubuntu desktop system

 - List item
```

> Cave-at

It will not work if someone installs the desktop without using ubuntu-desktop. But who does that?

> [Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#How_do_I_tell_if_my_question_is_Ubuntu_Server_related.3F)

- Before 12.04, Ubuntu server installs a server-optimized kernel by default. Since 12.04, there is no difference in kernel between Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server since linux-image-server is merged into linux-image-generic.

Comment: BTW, `$?` will be `1` if `dpkg -l` fails to list anything, `0` otherwise. Regarding `grep desktop` it will always match, either the package or the message saying it hasn't been found.

Comment: Ok this is my last edit I hope! Can you clean up comments too? >:D

Comment: I'm just reading the `dpkg` man page, but apparently this seems to work. If someone installs desktop without ubuntu-desktop, they should be savvy enought to fix the problems my script will cause, so it's all good! :P

Comment: `( dpkg -s "ubuntu-desktop" && Ubuntu_Flavor="desktop" ) > /dev/null 2>&1` works great, thanks!